# SOAP Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, soap

So I'm wanting to authenticate my SOAP web service with basic HTTP Authentication. I've searched the internet and all I find is...

```
$soapAuthArray = Array('login' => 'user', 
                       'password' => 'test) ;

$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost/test/ws/cow.wsdl", $soapAuthArray);
```

Great... so I know how to pass a user and password, but how do I do something with it?

I've created my own wsdl file, server, and client. Everything is currently working without authentication.

Thanks.
j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP SOAP extension is a little confusing. I'm using [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) instead for years now (but you have to disable PHP soap extension). You can find many examples coming with their library or check out this [article](http://www.beanizer.org/site/index.php/en/Articles/NuSOAP-HTTP-Authentication-and-HTTP-Proxy.html)

Comment: Thanks, I next to I need to setup a web service I'll look at using NuSoap. SOAP has poor documentation.